# select where only have 8 digit number

Tags: sql

I have question about how tow select serialnumber with condition just have 8 digit number.
For example :

12345678

12343546565

43764374

23728328372873

I just want select serial number 12345678 & 43764374.
So how can I match select only just serialnumber has 8 digit number

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please tag your DBMS? Is this column numeric or can also appear other characters?

Comment: yes can numeric or mix with character

Comment: So, please edit your question and be more precise: 1) Which serial numbers are possible? Can they be negative? Which characters can occur? 2) Which serial numbers should exactly be selected? Should the number Test12345678 be selected because it has 8 digits? Or should only numbers be found that consists of 8 digits and nothing else? Please improve your question by editing it and add all necessary clarifications. Do not use comments for that.

Comment: It's by the way extremely strange that you accepted an answer which does not match your description. The answer would select "NiceText" as matching serial number although it contains zero digits. Is this because your description is incorrect or because you don't want to put effort in asking your question in a good way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends a bit on which kind of database you have, but it will look something like this:

```
WHERE LEN(SerialNumber) = 8
```

or this:

```
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(SerialNumber) = 8
```

Comment: Why to answer a question with so much missing information? As the question currently stands, we know nothing about the possible content of this column. Your queries would for example also fetch 12345.67 as matching or test1234 as matching.

Answer (score 0):

With Bigquery you can do this:

```sql
WITH subtab AS 
(
SELECT [12345678,12343546565,43764374,23728328372873] AS serialnumber
)

SELECT serialnumber FROM subtab, UNNEST(subtab.serialnumber) as serialnumber
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(CAST(serialnumber as string)) = 8
```

Results:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Here you could select the serialnumber from the table where the serialnumbers are equals to 2 which means you should be using LENGTH as it returns the number of characters as we mentioned in the string which equals to 2

```
SELECT serialnumber
FROM TABLENAME
WHERE LENGTH(serialnumber) = 2;
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you edit your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: @Skully As i believe that will do the trick for him, I still think you're right and I will Edit my message Thanks in advance!